# Page Life Expectancy metric or equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Is there any analog of MS SQL Server PLE ([Page Life Expectancy](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/sql-server-page-life-expectancy-ple/ba-p/318572)) metric in Postgres?

I know only about cache hit ratio, which request look like:

```sql
    select sum(blks_hit)*100/sum(blks_hit+blks_read) as hit_ratio 
    from pg_stat_database;
```

However, I need to understand which request is consuming memory. That is, at the time of executing a heavy request, PLE will fall sharply. What metric(s) will help me with this in Postgres?

Comment: This is a great example of an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) -- instead of asking how to achieve your goal you suggest an incorrect approach to achieving it and ask why it doesn't work. So, what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres there isn't an equivalent of the Page Life Expectancy metric (which you [shouldn't be using](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/06/page-life-expectancy-doesnt-mean-jack-and-you-should-stop-looking-at-it/) anyway).

A combination of

```sql
select buffers_alloc from pg_stat_bgwriter
```

and

```sql
select shared_blks_hit, shared_blks_read, shared_blks_dirtied from pg_stat_statement
```

(and possibly other metrics from those two views) should give you a good picture of when a lot of blocks are being loaded into the shared buffers and who is responsible.